# What does a payable parameter mean in constructor?

Tags: solidity, payable

```
constructor(
    uint _biddingTime,
    address payable _beneficiary
) public {
    beneficiary = _beneficiary;
    auctionEndTime = now + _biddingTime;
}
```

This code is from the contract SimpleAuction in the solidity documentation. 
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/solidity-by-example.html

What does a payable parameter mean?

Answer (score 2):

In this example:

```
constructor(
    uint _biddingTime,
    address payable _beneficiary
)
```

> address payale

casts `_beneficiary` as Type: address payable

In Solidity an address can be `payable` which attaches the `.send()` and `.transfer()` methods. Otherwise, it's the same as `address _beneficiary`.

A constructor, or other function, can also have the `payable` modifier which is sort of what I thought the question was about, because on the title.

```
contructor(Type arg, Type arg) public payable { ...
```

With that usage, one can send Ether with the deployment transaction and it will add to the deployed contract's balance.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In example you mentioned `address payable _beneficiary` means that `_beneficiary` can receive ethers. With having `payable` keyword now `_beneficiary.send(etherAmount)` and `_beneficiary.transfer(etherAmount)` can be used in the contract logic.